# Is there a way to get fluent-nhibernate to compare a ValueObject's value to a string using QueryOver?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Following on from some of Vladimir Khorikov's courses on DDD, I have abstracted some primitive class properties into ValueObjects. For instance, the `Username` property of my `Account` entity was a string, but in order to validate it as a domain concept I have created a `Username` type.

This has caused the QueryOver to stop working, see code.

I get exception: `NHibernate.QueryException: 'could not resolve property: Username.Value of: PtPro.Domain.Account.Account'`

```
// Account.cs
public class Account : AggregateRoot
    {
        private string _username;
        public virtual Username Username
        {
            get => (Username)_username;
            set => _username = value;
        }
    } // Rest of class removed for brevity

// AccountMap.cs
    public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
    {
        public AccountMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);

            Map(x => x.Username).CustomType<string>().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);

            References(Reveal.Member<Account, Client>("Client"))
                .Cascade
                .SaveUpdate();
        }
    } // Rest of class removed

// AccountRepository.cs
        public Account GetWithClientByUsername(string username)
        {
            Account ac = null;
            Client cl = null;
            var account =  _session.QueryOver<Account>(() => ac)
                .JoinAlias(() => ac.Client, () => cl)
                .Where(() => ac.Username.Value == username)
                .SingleOrDefault<Account>();
            return account;
        }

// Username.cs
    public class Username : ValueObject<Username>
    {
        public string Value { get; }

        private Username() { }

        private Username(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public static Result<Username> Create(string username)
        {
            username = (username ?? string.Empty).Trim();

            if (username.Length == 0)
                return Result.Fail<Username>("Username is invalid");

            return Result.Ok(new Username(username));
        }

        public static implicit operator string(Username username)
        {
            return username.Value;
        }

        public static explicit operator Username(string username)
        {
            return Create(username).Value;
        }

        protected override bool EqualsCore(Username other)
        {
            return other.Value.Equals(Value);
        }

        protected override int GetHashCodeCore()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate's query objects are bad at supporting value objects. Try hql instead, it does honor such mappings.

```
string query = @"
    from Account a inner join fetch a.Client c
    where a.Username = :userName";

IList<Subscription> subscriptions = _session.CreateQuery(query)
    .SetParameter("userName", username)
    .List<Subscription>();
```

More info: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems [component mapping](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components) is a good fit for such value objects.

```
public class UsernameMap : ComponentMap<Username>
{
    public UsernameMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Value).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
    }
}

public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        //Use Component instead of Map for all Username mappings
        Component(x => x.Username);
    }
}
```